# which framework is best for hybrid android application

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, search-suggestion

I need a suggestion which framework is best for hybrid application developer whether flutter or react native because nowadays flutter git community is becoming strong but is this a best choice for native android developer

Comment: this question is opinion-based and should not be asked on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, someone like me, who uses Flutter will tell you to use Flutter. While someone using RN will tell you to use that. I can't give you an objective answer of what is better. So instead I'll just tell you some upsides of Flutter for people just learning it, and then you can compare it to whatever you know about RN.

1. Easy to get started with. Once you understand the basics of Flutter, you will be able to pull off pretty nice designs with little difficulty. The Structure makes code easy to read and maintainable.
2. Rendering. Flutter renders every pixel by itself. This is nice since it gives you more control of how everything will look on any device.
3. Great package support. Since Flutter is designed in a very modular way(the very concept of Widgets), it is very easy to import a package and get working components out of the box. And there are alot of packages out there that can help with anything from Animation to API interaction.
4. Firebase support. Flutter and Firebase are very closely linked. I don't use it myself currently, but many people do. And if you want to use Firebase as a backend, Flutter makes that very easy.

Flutter is certainly not quite as mature as RN is. But it has alot of upsides aswell. The popularity of Flutter is also increasing drastically, so support will only get better.

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help this really help me to understand the difference I will try to start flutter

Comment: @AsifAshraf Glad it helped. Good luck.